# Iterator issue on yield IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

I wrote a program designed to create a randomish list of numbers from a given starting point. It was a quick a dirty thing but I found an interesting effect when playing with it that I don't quite understand.

```
void Main()
{
    List<int> foo = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
    IEnumerable<int> bar = GetNumbers(foo);
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        foo = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
        var wibble = GetNumbers(foo);
        bar = bar.Concat(wibble);
    }
    Iterate(bar);
    Iterate(bar);
}

public void Iterate(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("iterating");
    foreach(int number in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}

public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers(List<int> input)
{
    //This function originally did more but this is a cutdown version for testing.
    while (input.Count>0)
    {
        int returnvalue = input[0];
        input.Remove(input[0]);
        yield return returnvalue;
    }
}
```

The output of runing this is:

```
iterating
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
iterating
```

That is to say the second time I iterate through `bar` immediately after it is empty.

I assume this is something to do with the fact that the first time I iterate that it empties the lists that are being used to generate the list and subsequently it is using these same lists that are now empty to iterate.

My confusion is on why this is happening? Why do my IEnumerables not start from their default state each time I enumerate over them? Can somebody explain what exactly I'm doing here?

And to be clear I know that I can solve this problem by adding a `.ToList()` to my call to `GetNumbers()` which forces immediate evaluation and storage of the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your iterator does start from its initial state. However, it modifies the list it's reading from, and once the list is cleared, your iterator doesn't have anything left to do. Basically, consider

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var enumerable = list.Where(i => i != 2);
foreach (var item in enumerable)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
list.Clear();
foreach (var item in enumerable)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

`enumerable` doesn't get changed by `list.Clear();`, but the results it gives do.

Comment: For some reason I expected it to work on a copy of the list so it could keep its initial state pristine and unchanged for secondary runs. I guess it makes sense that it doesn't do anything complicated like that. And with respect to your example I understand that one, I just thought that mine was different because the list is inside the enumerator. Maybe I need to look at what is actually generated byt eh compiler for that method...

Comment: It's basically the same thing, because it doesn't matter who removes items from the list, it only matters that they're already removed before starting your second `foreach`. No new list is created if you don't say a new list should be created, even if it would be useful for your specific scenario.

Comment: Yup. I think I got it now. I was forgetting basics of programming it seems thinking something mroe clever was happening. So basically the iterators created do all have a private field storing the list but its a reference to the same list so removing on one removes it on subsequent.

Comment: I've realised that what I expected to happen after your comments and some starting at decompiled version of the code is what would have happened if I'd put `var bang = new List<int>(input);` at the beginning of my enumerable method so that it would always store a new copy of the thing on each loop. I think I understand now why it didn't though. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your observation can be reproduced with this shorter version of the main method:

```
void Main() 
{ 
    List<int> foo = new List<int>(){1,2,3}; 
    IEnumerable<int> bar = GetNumbers(foo); 
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Count); // prints 3
    Iterate(bar); 
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Count); // prints 0
    Iterate(bar); 
}
```

What happens is the following:

When you call `GetNumbers` it isn't really being executed. It will only be executed when you iterate over the result. You can verify this by putting `Console.WriteLine(foo.Count);` between the call to `GetNumbers` and `Iterate`.
On the first call to `Iterate`, `GetNumbers` is executed and empties foo.
On the second call to `Iterate`, `GetNumbers` is executed again, but now foo is empty, so there is nothing left to return.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the lazy evaluation is what hit you. You see, when you create a `yield return`-style method, it's not executed immediately upon call. It'll be however executed as soon as you iterate over the sequence.

So, this means that the list won't be cleared during `GetNumbers`, but only during `Iterate`. In fact, the whole body of the function `GetNumbers` will be executed only during `Iterate`.

You problem is that you made your `IEnumersble`s depend not only on *inner* state, but on *outer* state as well. That outer state is the content of `foo` lists.

So, the all the lists are filled until you `Iterate` the first time. (The `IEnumerable` created by `GetNumbers` holds a reference to them, so the fact that you overwrite `foo` doesn't matter.) All the three are emptied during the first `Iterate`. Next, the next iteration starts with the same inner state, but changed outer state, giving different result.

I'd like to notice, that mutation and depending on outer state is generally frowned upon in functional programming style. The LINQ is actually a step toward functional programming, so it's a good idea to follow the FP's rules. So you could do better with just not removing the items from `input` in `GetNumbers`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was lazy evaluating, I think that and other clever things blinded me to the more simple problem that the iterator object only has a single copy of the list and that my problem was modifying that list in the method.